# First steps with rspec, want to test method in /lib/app_name/blah.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is rails 3, with rspec.

How to I create the template for my tests, and where should it be in the `/spec` folder?

would it be:

```
/spec/lib/app_name/
```

I have this in my GEM file:

```
 group :development, :test do
    gem 'ruby-debug'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'

    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
 end
```

What do I need to get my first test going now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the documentation at http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5